# How to "attribute all content to" specific user once delete user in wordpress

Tags: users

I have a question about how to attribute all content to specific user once delete any user in Wordpress.

Is there any idea how could I disable "Delete all content" option and set as default option "Attribute all content to:".

In user dropdown list of "Attribute all content to" I'd like to show only the value of specific user, with user_id = 1.

[image: Screenshot]